# Where is this Probability Mass Function defined?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For what value of $c$ and $\alpha$ is the function $p$, defined by:

$$ p(k) =\begin{cases} 
      ck^\alpha & for \ \  k = 1, 2, ... \\
            0 & otherwise 
   \end{cases}
$$

a mass function?

I think $\alpha$ must be $\alpha < -1$ because the sum must converge. But I get stuck at $c$. Does it have to be equal to $$\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^\alpha}$$

Comment: Short answer. Yes, because the sum of the probabilities must be $1$.

Comment: Thank you Ethan

Comment: You can answer your own question here (and accept the answer) so that the question does not remain on the unanswered queue and attract unnecessary attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of the probabilities must be 1.

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p(k)=1$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}ck^{\alpha}=1$$
$$c\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{\alpha}=1$$
$$c=\frac{1}{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{\alpha}}$$